# Seaborn: gridlines from secondary axis above data (with different ticks)

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am using seaborn and twinx to plot two lines in one figure. However, as replicated below, the blue line is below the horizontal line because it is overlayed by the second plot:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
l1 = sns.lineplot(x=[0,1,2],y=[1,2,3],color="#0188A8")
ax1 = plt.gca()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
l2 = sns.lineplot(x=[0,1,2], y=[100,200,300],color="#D42227")
plt.xlabel('Number of Selves',fontsize=13)
ax1.set_xticks([0,1,2])
ax1.set_yticks([0,1,2])
ax2.set_yticks([100,200,300])
```

[image]

After doing some googling, I found [this](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7984) which was close, but didn't help. Trying out their solution, the axis ticks will get distorted, as both lines are plotted on the second plot:

```
ax1 = plt.gca()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
l1 = sns.lineplot(x=[0,1,2],y=[1,2,3],color="#0188A8")
l2 = sns.lineplot(x=[0,1,2], y=[100,200,300],color="#D42227")
plt.xlabel('Number of Selves',fontsize=13)
ax1.set_xticks([0,1,2])
ax1.set_yticks([0,1,2])
ax2.set_yticks([100,200,300])
```

[image]

My question is, how can the blue line be on top of the horizontal grid lines while maintaining the ticks to be at the same position as they are in the first picture?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot easily obtain the desired effect because all the artists of `ax2` are drawn above the artists of `ax1`, regardless of their respective z-order.

The only "good" solution that I can suggest, is, as you had found out, draw both lines on `ax2`, but you have to use the data transform of `ax1` for the first line so that it matches the numbers on the left axis.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

l1 = sns.lineplot(x=[0,1,2],y=[1,2,3],color="#0188A8", ax=ax2, transform=ax1.transData)
l2 = sns.lineplot(x=[0,1,2], y=[100,200,300],color="#D42227", ax=ax2)

ax1.set_xlabel('Number of Selves',fontsize=13)
ax1.set_xticks([0,1,2])
ax1.set_yticks([0,1,2])
ax2.set_yticks([100,200,300])
ax1.set_ylim(-0.5,3.5)
```

Note that, because there are actually no data on `ax1`, you have to manually specify the y-axis limits, it won't autoscale for you.

[image]